make4ht: uppercase Greek letters inside tikzpicture environment don't show and are italicized outside
I'm converting a document with tikzpictures containing uppercase Greek letters ($\Delta$, $\Omega$). In the html output only $\Gamma$, $\Theta$, $\Lambda$ and $Phi$ are shown when they are inside a tikzpicture environment, itself either inside a figure environement or not. An inline tikzpicture has the same problem, while  inline \tikz\node{...} works better (except for a domfilter warning: Unbalanced Tag (/mi).
I convert with make4ht -ul main "mathml,mathjax" as my real document compiles to pdf using lualatex, and I use siunitx macros which cooperates nicely with the "mathml,mathjax" option. Note that in order to get the svg images to show in the browser I manually replace img tags with embed tags in the generated main.html.
My MWE (main.tex)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) (delta) [label=90:An omega $\Omega$, pin=-90:A lowercase greek $\alpha$] 
        {$\Gamma \Delta \Theta \Lambda \Xi \Pi \Sigma \Upsilon \Phi \Psi \Omega$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Uppercase greek letters:
        $\Gamma \Delta \Theta \Lambda \Xi \Pi \Sigma \Upsilon \Phi \Psi \Omega$.}
\end{figure}
Uppercase greek as inline tikz:
\tikz\node{$\Gamma \Delta \Theta \Lambda \Xi \Pi \Sigma \Upsilon \Phi \Psi \Omega$};.

Normal uppercase greek:
$\Gamma \Delta \Theta \Lambda \Xi \Pi \Sigma \Upsilon \Phi \Psi \Omega$

Uppercase greek in tikzpicture but outside float.
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (delta)
        {$\Gamma \Delta \Theta \Lambda \Xi \Pi \Sigma \Upsilon \Phi \Psi \Omega$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The questions:

How do I get all uppercase Greek letters to show inside a tikzpicture?
The uppercase Greek letters outside the tikzpicture environment are in italics. I'd like them to be upright as in the pdf. The inline \tikz\node{...} has them upright. How can I achieve this behavior in both cases?
My workaround replacing <img> tags with <embed> feels like it shouldn't be necessary. What am I doing wrong?

I use texlive 2024.2 installed via Archlinux' package manager.

For 3. above I found that the css styling prefers-color-scheme caused the issue. All my figures were color-inverted to white on a white background. Sorry for the noise.

There are two problems. Some uppercase Greek letters are incorrectly redefined in the MathML output of TeX4ht, so they don't work correctly inside pictures. The other problem is caused by math inside the \tikz command, and I cannot find a solution that would work in all cases. I had to introduce a workaround, a command \mathtikz that will put \tikz to a picture if TeX4ht is used.
Here is your updated sample with the new command:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\mathtikz[1]{\tikz{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) (delta) [label=90:An omega $\Omega$, pin=-90:A lowercase greek $\alpha$] 
        {$\Gamma \Delta \Theta \Lambda \Xi \Pi \Sigma \Upsilon \Phi \Psi \Omega$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Uppercase greek letters:
        $\Gamma \Delta \Theta \Lambda \Xi \Pi \Sigma \Upsilon \Phi \Psi \Omega$.}
\end{figure}
Uppercase greek as inline tikz:
\mathtikz{\node{$\Gamma \Delta \Theta \Lambda \Xi \Pi \Sigma \Upsilon \Phi \Psi \Omega$};}.

Normal uppercase greek:
$\Gamma \Delta \Theta \Lambda \Xi \Pi \Sigma \Upsilon \Phi \Psi \Omega$

Uppercase greek in tikzpicture but outside float.
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (delta)
        {$\Gamma \Delta \Theta \Lambda \Xi \Pi \Sigma \Upsilon \Phi \Psi \Omega$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

You can then use the following configuration file that fixes Greek letters and redefines \mathtikz to produce pictures:
\Preamble{xhtml}

\catcode`\:=11
% we must restore commands that were already redefined in MathML
\def\:temp#1#2{\let#1\relax\DeclareMathSymbol{#1}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"#2}}
\:temp\Delta{01}
\:temp\Psi{09}
\:temp\Xi{04}
\:temp\Pi{05}
\:temp\Sigma{06}
\:temp\Upsilon{07}
\:temp\Omega{0A}
\def\:temp#1#2{\def\:tempa{\PauseMathClass{\HCode{<mi mathvariant="normal">}\ht:special{t4ht@+\string&{35}x#2{59}}\a:HChar\HCode{</mi>}}\EndPauseMathClass}\HLet#1\:tempa}
\:temp\Gamma{0393}
\:temp\Delta{0394}
\:temp\Theta{0398}
\:temp\Lambda{039B}
\:temp\Xi{039E}
\:temp\Pi{03A0}
\:temp\Sigma{03A3}
\:temp\Upsilon{03A5}
\:temp\Phi{03A6}
\:temp\Psi{03A8}
\:temp\Omega{03A9}

% fix the error with math inside \tikz
\renewcommand\mathtikz[1]{\Picture+{}\tikz{#1}\EndPicture}
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble

Compile using:
 $ make4ht -c config.cfg -l main "mathml,mathjax"

This is the result:

I've fixed issues with Greek letters in TeX4ht sources, so this should be included in a future version of your distro.

Thanks Michal. On my installation your config file makes the greek uppercase letters upright, but except $\Gamma$ $\Theta$ $\Lambda$ and $\Phi$ they still do not show up in the tikz picture, i.e. the remaining letters only show in the figure caption and on the line "Normal uppercase greek:". As this appears to be specific to my installation, is there any information I can provide that would be helpful?

@krone I see it now as well. It worked for me because of some immediate files. I've uploaded a new version of the config file, it should hopefully work now.
